# How to create an efficient timer in React Native with Expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying to create a timer in my app that shows on the screen as the user performs a task, counting up and updating every millisecond. I have tried a few different things, but everything that I have tried has caused serious issues with the rest of the screen, as I assume the main thread is being taken over by the timer.

I have looked into available packages, but can't seem to find anything that works in an Expo managed workflow. Any ideas how best to solve this problem? Below is my current implementation, but as I said, it is very inefficient and not usable.

```js
const [timer, setTimer] = useState(0);
const startTime = new Date();

const getElapsedTime = () => {
    setTimer((new Date().getTime() - startTime.getTime()) / 1000);
};

setInterval(getElapsedTime, 1000);

return (
    <Text>{ timer }</Text>
);
```